# Axon 4 - Cluster access configuration in Client application

Tags: axon

**Setup**

- Got Axon Server 4.x Enterprise trial license
- Have deployed 3 nodes with 1 leader

What is recommended configuration in the client application? 
Should it contain all Axon Server host address (`ip:port`), comma separated in the follow property?

```
axon.axonserver.servers = {insert-list-here}
```

Is there any recommendation, on how to ensure location transperancy in order to handle add/remove nodes from cluster scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axon.axonserver.servers should contain all admin nodes for the Axon Server cluster. When the application tries to set up a connection the admin node will redirect it to the correct Axon Server node, based on the application's tags and the already connected applications.